# Graph Explorer does not appear to support EDU endpoints

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

Currently, Graph Explorer does not appear to support EDU endpoints. Is there a way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to your descriptions, I presume you want to find whether there is a wat to support EDU endpoints or not.

Base on my test, we can use the API like this:

`GET /education/schools`

It will return a collection of [educationSchool](http://%20%20https://developer.microsoft.com/zh-cn/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/educationschool) objects in the response body.

In [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/educationroot_list_schools), we can find that this API support the work or school account. If we use a personal microsoft account to login the Graph Explore, it will not support the EDU endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The default tenant (i.e. the tenant data you get when you *haven't* logged into Graph Explorer) does include Edu data.

If you are authenticating, you will only be able to call the Edu endpoints if you have consented to the Edu scopes *and* your tenant is an Office 365 Education instance. These endpoints will not work with a non-Edu O365 tenant.